# Connecting to HTTPS service in TIBCO

Tags: ssl, https, tibco

We're trying to connect to external HTTPS service in Tibco?
However upon clicking SSL url, it asked for certificate PEM file. May I know what's the reason?

The issue is external HTTPS service that I am trying to connect is authenticated by user name & password, and not via certificate.

Any information or reference is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

He is asking actually about the public certificate of the server you want to connect to. That the way to check that the server is really who it says it is, and therefore you ensure that the connection is trusted, and you are connecting where really you want.